# Inserting UIKit content into a SwiftUI view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm sorry if the title is confusing, i'm kind of new to the whole thingy.

I'm trying to integrate PassBase ID verification to my app, which is built using SwiftUI, their documentation offers instructions using Swift and view Controllers.
My question is, is there a way to insert the Swift code part into my SwiftUI view?

The code example from their Documentation:

```
import Passbase
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, PassbaseDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    PassbaseSDK.delegate = self
    // Optional - You can prefill the email to skip that step.
    Passbase.prefillUserEmail = "testuser@yourproject.com"
    let button = PassbaseButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 90, width: 300, height: 60))
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func onFinish(identityAccessKey: String) {
  print("onFinish with identityAccessKey \(identityAccessKey)")
}

func onSubmitted(identityAccessKey: String) {
  print("onSubmitted with identityAccessKey \(identityAccessKey)")
}

func onError(errorCode: String) {
  print("onError with code \(errorCode)")
}

func onStart() {
  print("onStart")
}
}
```

As i understand this part of code should create a button in a VC.
My goal is to add this button with functionality to my SwiftUI view.

Full Documentation: https://docs.passbase.com/ios#general

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Comment: You mean *Insert **UIKit** into SwiftUI*. [Here is an Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic strategy is to use a `View` that represents the content you want to bring in from a `UIViewController`.  Your `View` is going to conform to `UIViewCotrollerRepresentable` and use the functions of that protocol to create and manage the `UIKit` content.

The `UIViewControllerRepresentable` documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/)

And, as was commented on your original post by vadian, there is [A tutorial with sample code](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit)

With the sample code above, I would rename "ViewController" to be something like `PassBaseViewController` or `PBViewController`, then you would create a `View` that derives from `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

You end up with a file called PBViewController.swift that has your code from above:

```
import Passbase
import UIKit

class PBViewController: UIViewController, PassbaseDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    PassbaseSDK.delegate = self
    // Optional - You can prefill the email to skip that step.
    Passbase.prefillUserEmail = "testuser@yourproject.com"
    let button = PassbaseButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 90, width: 300, height: 60))
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

... and the rest of the code from your question here ...
```

Then (probably in another file, but not necessarily) you could create the SwiftUIView that uses that view controller:

```
struct PassBaseView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = PBViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PBViewController {
        return PBViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PBViewController, context: Context) {
        /* code here to make changes to the view controller if necessary when this view is updated*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer!
In the function that is provided in the example on Apples website, do i just import the whole UIKit class? Sorry for the confusion it's just i have 0 idea how UIKit works. :/

Comment: Let me edit the answer with a bit more detail

Comment: Thanks! Just as you posted the edit,i did the exact same thing! I'm experiencing a problem that when i want to include this button in a view, it's not tappable, the only way i achieved it to work is to use a Navigationlink to the view