# Changing bounds of a SwiftUI View when inserting UIKit functionality

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I am currently trying to insert UIKit functionality into SwiftUI as the API I am using has a tutorial with UIKit and my project is SwiftUI.  For context, this is the exact post I used to implement this functionality: [Inserting UIKit content into a SwiftUI view hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69757135/inserting-uikit-content-into-a-swiftui-view-hierarchy)

As a result, I have 2 different files: PBViewController and PassbaseView.  The preview of PassbaseView looks like so: [image: preview]

As a result, calling PassBaseView() in the SwiftUI View where I desire to have the button doesn't result in what I want, as the whitespace around the button is included, when I just want the button.  How do I only get the button to be inserted when I call PassBaseView()? My code is exactly the same as the post I linked.

My initial idea was to do this in the PBViewController file:

```
self.view.frame.size.width = 300
self.view.frame.size.height = 60
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the PassBaseView() into an additional VStack gets the desired functionality.